# R markdown - inserting HTML tag within R code (programatically)

Tags: r-markdown

I would like to add HTML tag for section heading for easier search through browser (which is not possible in PNG). Is there any easier option? I can not use "asis" option. I am looping for each test and it is not possible to write segment of the code.

I even creating function to output HTML using cat() from main R program but it didn't work.